# Turn svg image into button

Tags: html, css, angular, svg

I was able to develop to this point, but I wanted the "image" to be a button.

Along with the post, I provide the codepen link too see my html and css.

https://codepen.io/hefty95/pen/ZEEQMOq

```
    <div id="Grupo_2141">
        <div id="Grupo_5_A56_Group_14">
            <svg class="Ret_ngulo_1_A56_Rectangle_12">
                <rect fill="rgba(202,206,213,1)" id="Ret_ngulo_1_A56_Rectangle_12" rx="12" ry="12" x="0" y="0" width="141" height="24">
                </rect>
            </svg>
            <div id="My_Notifications">
                <span>My Notifications</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: WHat  do you exactly mean when you say button ? Do you want it to look like as if it clickable ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek    Yes, that's it.

Comment: You asked it to look similar to button so I have provided `css` as an answer. You need to clarify more if you are not getting what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap it in a `button`. The [button tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) permits [phrasing content](http://%20%09Phrasing%20content), which includes [SVG tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg).

Comment: When I use the button tag, the button format changes :(

Comment: Yeah. You can suppress that with css. Whether it's better to do the semantically explicit thing and then patch the styling, or to use CSS to get the particular stuff you want concisely (as [Shashank Vivek suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58364951/10135377)), depends on context and is ultimately subjective. If the thing is a "button" then I think it would be best as a `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a function or script when you click the image, you can add a

```
<svg … (click)="yourFunction()"></svg>
```

-Event to your rect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [this demo code](http://plnkr.co/edit/LChWsBk1a6qZc5c2TTXB?p=preview)

try adding more bahaviors in css

```
    #my-btn{
      cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
        #my-btn:active{
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }
```

Since your question is tagged as `angular`, you can `(click)` on the `svg` to add some events as we;;

Comment: With cursor: pointer  I can get what I want, but will it just work as a button?

Comment: @Dinho: Like I said earlier, when you say `button` , `1.` You need to make it look like button, `2.` add `(click)` of angular to add some events. Update your question with more details about `what you expect from that "button"` , if my answer is not covering everything

Comment: Already updated the code and managed to get the desired design. However, I couldn't get a tag button, could you help me?

Comment: @Dinho : Your code does not render `svg` , you have to fix it.  I am not sure about your intention of getting `button tag` , I am unable to understand the problem.  I cant help more unless you elaborate it better